# Azure Log4Net Appender avoid create a xml file for each entry

Tags: azure, log4net

I installed the `log4net.Appender.Azure` and got it working with Azure blob storage. My issue is that it is creating an log.xml file per each log record, that's annoying.

Here is an example log file which is created for one log record,

```
<LogEntry>

<UserName>IIS APPPOOL\myapp.web</UserName>

<TimeStamp>05/18/2016 16:14:13</TimeStamp>

<ThreadName>82</ThreadName>

<LoggerName>App.Common.Logger</LoggerName>

<Level>ERROR</Level>

<Identity/>

<Domain>/LM/W3SVC/14/ROOT-5-131080247274265317</Domain>

<CreatedOn>05/18/2016 06:17:21</CreatedOn>

<RenderedMessage>Test Error msg log4net</RenderedMessage>

<Location>MyApp.Web.App.User.Controllers.UserController.SignIn(C:\...\Source\Controllers\UserController.cs:63)</Location>

</LogEntry>
```

Is there a configuration to avoid this and have something like a daily log or rolling mechanism? Couldn't find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using this one ? https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Appender.Azure 
If so you can't according to the doc that you can find on github (https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.Azure).

One option would be to append log in an Azure Table : so you would get 1 row (instead of 1 file) for new each log record.

```
<appender name="AzureTableAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AzureTableAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
   <param name="TableName" value="testLoggingTable"/>
   <!-- You can either specify a connection string or use the ConnectionStringName property instead -->
   <param name="ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"/>
   <!--<param name="ConnectionStringName" value="GlobalConfigurationString" />-->
   <!-- You can specify this to make each LogProperty as separate Column in TableStorage, 
    Default: all Custom Properties were logged into one single field -->
   <param name="PropAsColumn" value="true" />
   <!-- You can specify this to make each LogProperty as separate Column in TableStorage, 
    Default: all Custom Properties were logged into one single field -->
   <param name="PropAsColumn" value="true" />
   <param name="PartitionKeyType" value="LoggerName" />
 </appender>
```

Or you can update the code provided on github https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.Azure